# Showing $\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\exp(i(v-w))t}{i(v-w)} |^{a+2\pi}_{a} = 0$, for $v \neq w$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am trying to prove an exponential identity and am stuck at:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\exp(i(v-w))t}{i(v-w)} |^{a+2\pi}_{a} = 0, \quad \text{for $v \neq w$}$$

The textbook suggests that this is equal because $\exp$ is $2\pi$ periodic which seems clear to me. But wouldn't it also be possible to rewrite this as:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\exp(i(v-w))2\pi}{i(v-w)} = \frac{\exp(i(v-w))}{i(v-w)}$$
?

Comment: I believe the confusion is that there is an implicit set of brackets. In particular, $\exp(i(v-w))t$ is supposed to mean $\exp\color{red}{(}(i(v-w))t\color{red}{)}$, i.e., the $t$ is part of the exponent. In that case, along with the additional assumption (perhaps already explicitly stated in the book in some fashion) that $v-w$ is an integer, what the textbook wrote would then make sense.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Note that, as it's currently written, your result is correct, and the textbook's result is incorrect. Also, rather than using an extra set of brackets, the textbook could have moved the $t$ to within the current set of brackets, i.e., written it as $\exp(i(v-w)t)$ instead.

Comment: Note I haven't posted an answer because, although you agree that what I wrote "makes a lot of sense", I assume there are previous details before the exponential identity which either corroborate my suggestion, or suggest something different. If you provide that information by editing your question then, although I could write an appropriate answer, I suggest you write an answer instead.